# common object zend framework for Zend_Filter_StripTags which can be used throughout the application?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to create a function in bootstrap to intitiate object for Zend_Filter_StripTags, so that I can use its object throughout the application.

```
protected function _initHtmlFilter() {  
 $allowedTags = array('p','b','br','strong'); // Allowed tags 
 $allowedAttributes = array('href'); // Allowed attributes  
 $stripTags = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowedTags,$allowedAttributes); 
}
```

but I'm unable to use this object($stripTags) in any controller.

Comment: I got it, I can use Zend_Registry for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an Controller Action Helper for this:

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_StripTags extends
    Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * StripTags
     *
     * @param string $input String to strip tags from
     *
     * @return string String without tags
     */
    public function stripTags($input) 
    {
        $allowedTags = array('p','b','br','strong'); // Allowed tags 
        $allowedAttributes = array('href'); // Allowed attributes  
        $stripTags = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowedTags,$allowedAttributes);

        // return input without tags
        return $stripTags->filter($input);

    }
}


// example in indexAction
$noTags = $this->_helper->stripTags('<h2>TEST</h2>');
```

You have to add the path to your helpers in your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.My_Controller_Action_Helper_ = "My/Controller/Action/Helper"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zend registry for this:

```
  protected function _initHtmlFilter() {
    $allowedTags = array('p','b','br','strong'); // Allowed tags
    $allowedAttributes = array('href'); // Allowed attributes
    $stripTags = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowedTags,$allowedAttributes);
    Zend_Registry::set('zend_strip_tags', $stripTags);
}
```

and can access it any where like :

```
Zend_Registry::get('zend_strip_tags');
```